# javascript can't get object property value

Tags: javascript, object, properties, attributes

I have javascript object like below:

```
var row = {
              'fileAttribute' : {
                  '.\K\ar- #%i\.n/a': true,
                  'size': '2040',
                  'type' : 'pdf'
                  }
    };
```

But when I try to get value of row.fileAttribute['.\K\ar- #%i.n/a'] , I get undefined instead of true.

I know that it's beacuse my property name contains a special characters. 
row.fileAttribute.hasOwnProperty('.\K\ar- #%i.n/a') returns false.

I tried to extract this property values by _.values(row.fileAttribute['.\K\ar- #%i.n/a']) , however I got empty array.

My console:
[image]

Here is a example of this issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/fvu2pqzz/8/

I appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: The code you link to is significantly different to `row.fileAttributes['.\K\ar- #%i.n/a'])`

Comment: Typo mistake definitely. It should be `fileAttribute` without an `s`, shouldn'tit?

Comment: Seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/fvu2pqzz/8/

Comment: you can't access the property by dot notation, since it contains invalid characters. The bracket notation will work

Comment: Please look at my console screenshot.
http://i.stack.imgur.com/v9eRj.jpg

Comment: The screenshot says you have a key named `.K\ar- #%i.n/a`, which means the \ has been escaped, so you need to use `item.fileAttributes['.K\\ar- #%i.n/a']` to get it.

Comment: @AminPourhadi your js fiddle is working fine, try opening browsers console and then click run : http://jsfiddle.net/fvu2pqzz/8/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation)

```
console.info(row.entity.fileAttribute['.Kar- #%i.n/a']);
```

```js
var row = {
            'entity' : {
                'fileAttribute' : {
                    '.\K\ar- #%i\.n/a': true,
                    'size': '20',
                    'qty' : '50'
                },
                'part2' : {
                    'name': 'Part 2',
                    'size': '15',
                    'qty' : '60'
                }
            }
        };
        
console.info(row.entity.fileAttribute['.Kar- #%i.n/a']);
```

Comment: @AminPourhadi I just tested it with your object and it returned true

Comment: @AminPourhadi you must be doing something else

Comment: Thanks @shivgre, but this code works correctly in fiddle and in my doesn't worked :(